# Why Copy constructor is NOT called to copy the temporary object to the new defined object

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Y {
public:
    Y(int ) {
        cout << "Y(int)\n";
    }
    Y(const Y&) {
        cout << " Y(const Y&)\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    Y obj1 = 2; // Line 1
}
```

Output: Y(int)

Expected Output: Y(int)
                 Y(const Y&)

Question> Based on my understanding, Line 1 will first create a temporary object Y(2), and then assign the temporary object to `obj1`. Thus, I expect both `Y(int)` and `Y(const Y&)` are called. But the output from vs2010 only reports the first one(i.e. `Y(int)`). Why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why?

Because under certain conditions (specified by paragraph 12.8/31 of the C++11 Standard) calls to the copy constructor or move constructor can be elided even though those special functions (or the destructor) have side effects:

> This elision of copy/move
>   operations, called copy elision, is permitted in the following circumstances (which may be combined to
>   eliminate multiple copies):
>
> —  [...]
>
> — when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference (12.2) would be copied/moved
>   to a class object with the same cv-unqualified type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by
>   constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the omitted copy/move
>
> — [...]

This is the only exception to the so-called "*as-if*" rule, which normally constrains the kind of transformations (optimizations) that a compiler can perform on a program in order to preserve its observable behavior.

Notice, that the above mechanism is called *copy elision* - even when it's actually a call to the move constructor that is being elided.

Answer (score 4):

This is because the constructor has only one parameter and it's not marked `explicit`, so the compiler automatically turns:

```
Y obj1 = 2;
```

Into:

```
Y obj1(2);
```

To prevent this behaviour, use:

```
explicit Y(int ) {
    cout << "Y(int)\n";
}
```

(and compilation will fail in your case).

Comment: The fact that `explicit` causes a compiler error means that it does not magically turn `= 2` into `(2)`. All `explicit` does is prevent implicit conversions to your type.

Comment: _"to prevent this behaviour [...] and compilation will fail in your case."_

Answer (score 3):

This is called [**`copy initialization`**](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/036.htm). `Y(int )` is a conversion constructor. that is

> single-parameter constructor that is declared without the function
>   specifier explicit

the compiler is allowed to elide the extra copy and use your [**`conversion constructor`**](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/cplr384.htm). Which means

```
Y obj1 = 2; // Line 1
```

is equivalent to

```
Y obj1(2); // Line 1
```

Comment: See Stefano's answer for further discussion (Andy's is correct). An `explicit` causing an error means that these are by no means equivalent.

Comment: Copy initialization is not equivalent to direct initialization. The former is conceptually achieved by constructing a temporary from the initializing expression (`2`), and then move-constructing or copy-constructing `obj1` from that temporary. However, the compiler is allowed to elide this call to the move constructor or copy constructor per 12.8/31 (see my answer)